# Evaluate $\int\int_B (x+y)dxdy$, where B is the rectangle in the xy plane with vertices (0,1), (1,0), (3,4)and (4,3).

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So I found the linear equations of the sides of the rectangle:

$y=-x+1, y=x-1, y=-x+7, y=x+1$

How do I use this information to construct a transformation $T(x(u,v), y(u,v))$ for a simple rectangle in the $uv$ coordinates?

The rest I know how to do. I'm puzzled on how to find a transformation that makes $B^*$ a simple rectangle flush with the axis of $uv$.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: Let $u = x+y, v = x-y$. Can you take it to the next step?

Comment: Do I use this and the linear equations to solve for x and y in terms of u and v?

Comment: Yes, you do. The above $2$ equations set the limits of the integral and solve for $x,y$ in terms of $u,v$ as well.

Comment: Im confused as to how exactly express x, y in terms of u, v. Since I have four linear equations, do I have multiple expressions of x and y at each intersection of the linear equations?

Answer (score 0):

A geometric way is to note that if $$x_c=\frac{1}{\mu(B)}\int_{B} x\,dx\,dy\\y_c=\frac{1}{\mu(B)}\int_{B} y\,dx\,dy$$ then $(x_c,y_c)$ is the center of mass of $B$. (This is true for *any* measurable $B$.)

So you are looking at $\mu(B)(x_c+y_c)$. And the center of mass of and area of a rectangle are pretty easy to compute.